# connecting to remote mongo db server and running clone

Tags: mongodb, migration, mongo-shell

I am migrating from server OLD at the old hosting company to server NEW at the new hosting company.

I want to run the clone command so I clone the mongoDB from OLD to NEW.

For OLD:
The public ip address is: 44.55.66.77. 
The machine login user name is: admin, and the password is password

What is the right way to do this?

So far I can't even log into the server OLD

So far I have tried the following command prompts on NEW:

```
mongo -u admin -p password 44.55.66.77

mongo remote-ip:44.55.77.66 -u admin -p password
```

That don't work

I also tried this from mongo shell:

```
db.CopyDatabase('OldDb', 'NewDb', '44.55.66.77', 'admin', 'password')
```

and I get: the "could not connect to server" error message

Answer (score 0):

Aside from firewall considerations in order to copy data between MongoDB servers, `db.copyDatabase()` (aka the `copydb` command) has a number of important [usage caveats](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/#behavior) including:

- `copydb` does not produce point-in-time snapshots of the source database; writing data to the source or destination database during the copy process will result in divergent data sets
- `copydb` does not lock the destination server during its operation, so the copy will occasionally yield to allow other operations to complete.

There is also a known issue that `copydb` may not work with the role-based privileges in MongoDB 2.4 if you have authentication enabled (see [SERVER-8213](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/), which was recently fixed in the 2.5.x development releases).

A much better approach to migrating your data would be to restore from a normal backup using `mongodump`/`mongorestore` or file system snapshots.  The [Backup & Recovery](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/) section of the MongoDB manual has tutorials covering procedures for different deployment types.